# Destroy or set global variable to nil, once the browser is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser, global-variables

I declared a global variable in my `rails` application controller as `$decrypted_attessec = "verified decrypted cookie"` and I am accessing it across all my controllers. Once I close the browser window, global variable must be set to nil or destroyed, which is not being done.

In my case, it always holds initial value which is `"verified decrypted cookie"` in this case, however, server restart destroys the global variable and re-initialise it, which I want to be done on closing of browser too.

**My code:**

*application_controller.rb*

```
 def validate_user
    $decrypted_attessec = "verfied decrypted cookie"
      #I am getting value of $decrypted_attessec as verfied decrypted cookie from different action which would be either an empty or non-empty string
    if !$decrypted_attessec.empty?
      #redirect_to clicked path
    else
      redirect_to "login url"
    end
  end
```

*Welcome_controller.rb < application_controller.rb*

```
if $decrypted_attessec.empty?
  before_action :validate_user, :except => [:index, :csplogin]
end
```

Where I went wrong with the code?

Comment: Ruby on Rails is stateless, so closing your browser will have no effect. Global variables are generally considered a bad practice. It sounds like you might want a session variable? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If there are many browsers connected to your server, then when to nullify the global variable?

Comment: detecting when the browser closes is not built into rails, you need to use AJAX or websockets for that.

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain what you try to achieve? Why does your application need to know when a user closes the browser?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a authentication feature, with a global variable in the app. Is that correct? Are you aware that multiple users might share the same variable in that case and how that might affect the app's security?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `@global_variable` isn't a global variable at all. It is, in fact, an instance variable of an object of your class.

Secondly, global variables are defined with a preceding `$`, for example, `$global_variable`. See [this excellent post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) to read more about the implications of using global variables.

Last, but not the least, global variables will not depend on closing and opening of the browser. I recommend elaborating your use-case more to get a better hit of solving your problem.